# Is it possible to have a union of url and FilePath in Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

I wonder if this would somehow be possible:

```py
class Picture(BaseModel):
    src: Union[FilePath, stricturl(allowed_schemes=["https"])]
```

I have this test, which is failing, because I think it is trying to apply `FilePath` to the url... I could reverse this but that does not make a difference because then, file paths are going to be parsed as urls. I know this is very tricky, I just wonder why a url is recognized as an interal file path (https protocol etc.)

```py
    def test_parse_component_chapter_optional_picture_src_accepts_url():
        err_msg = ("Error in /chapter: URL scheme not permitted:"
                   " \"picture->src: ... \"")
        chapter, err = parse_component_chapter({
            "picture": {
                "src": "http://www.robingruenke.com",
                "height": "250px"
            }
        })
        assert err == err_msg and chapter is None
```

Maybe there is a solution for this ?

Comment: the test expects an error because of given http ... I test for invalid url

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `Union`'s is unexpected coercion, wherein the value is forced into the first type that could handle the value. From the [Pydantic docs on Unions](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions):

> ```
> class User(BaseModel):
>     id: Union[int, str, UUID]
>     name: str
> ```
>
> ... pydantic will attempt to 'match' any of the types defined under `Union` and will use the first one that matches. In the above example the `id` of `user_03` was defined as a `uuid.UUID` class (which is defined under the attribute's `Union` annotation) but as the `uuid.UUID` can be marshalled into an `int` it chose to match against the `int` type and disregarded the other types.

It makes sense for you to expect that a `"http://..."` URL wouldn't match `FilePath`, but Pydantic's [`FilePath`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#pydantic-types) is just:

> like `Path`, but the path must exist and be a file

and [`Path`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#standard-library-types) is just the Python standard library type [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path), and Pydantic just:

> simply uses the type itself for validation by passing the value to `Path(v)`

Checking `pathlib.Path` behavior directly, it does accept an HTTP URL:

```
In [28]: from pathlib import Path

In [29]: Path("http://www.robingruenke.com")
Out[29]: PosixPath('http:/www.robingruenke.com')
```

and the actual error raised when using `FilePath` is just about that the "*path must exist*". In your test, you are expecting that the error would ***only*** be about the wrong URL scheme (`"URL scheme not permitted"`), when in fact, Pydantic raises 2 validation errors:

```
In [26]: class Picture(BaseModel):
    ...:     src: Union[FilePath, stricturl(allowed_schemes=["https"])]
    ...: 

In [27]: pic = Picture(src="http://www.robingruenke.com")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pic = Picture(src="http://www.robingruenke.com")

File ~/path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Picture
src
  file or directory at path "http:/www.robingruenke.com" does not exist (type=value_error.path.not_exists; path=http:/www.robingruenke.com)
src
  URL scheme not permitted (type=value_error.url.scheme; allowed_schemes={'https'})
```

1 error from `FilePath`, that the local file doesn't exist.
1 error from `stricturl`, that the scheme `"http`" is not allowed.

That would cause your `assert err == err_msg` to fail, because you actually have to check for 2 sets of validation errors, and the 1st error isn't even about the wrong URL scheme.

A workaround I would suggest here is, instead of a `Union` of different types, is [to implement your own validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) for the `src` field. It seems the requirement is that `src` should either be a locally existing file path or an HTTPS URL. You can use the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) standard library module for parsing URLs.

```
class Picture(BaseModel):
    src: str

    @validator("src", pre=True)
    def validate_src(cls, value: Any) -> AnyUrl:
        url_parts = urlparse(value)
        is_ok = True

        if url_parts.scheme and url_parts.scheme != "https":
            is_ok = False
        elif not Path(url_parts.path).exists():
            is_ok = False

        if not is_ok:
            raise ValueError("src must be either existing local file path or HTTPS URL")

        return value
```

```
def test_src_is_local_path_exists():
    pic = Picture(src="/local/directory/test.png")
    assert pic.src

def test_src_is_local_path_does_not_exist():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError) as exc:
        Picture(src="/file/that/does/not/exist")

    assert exc.value.errors()[0]["msg"] == "src must be either existing local file path or HTTPS URL"

def test_src_is_url_is_https():
    pic = Picture(src="https://www.robingruenke.com")
    assert pic.src

def test_src_is_url_is_not_https():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError) as exc:
        Picture(src="http://www.robingruenke.com")

    assert exc.value.errors()[0]["msg"] == "src must be either existing local file path or HTTPS URL"
```